# Merge/concatenate select properties in javascript/typescript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, javascript-objects

I have a function that pulls drugs into a javascript object from the server via **odata** and it currently returns an array of drugs in json.

How do I create a display name property on the return object that concatenates/joins certain properties so that the returned drug array has a new property called displayname that should equal to following string:

```
 "Dosage:" + drug.Name + "-" + drug.AlternateNames + " (" + drug.Type + ") " + drug.Indication
```

Code to pull from the server is below:

```
getDsTeamSiteDrugs = function () {

    var drugsUrl = environment.odataUrl + "Drug";

    return this.http.get(drugsUrl + '?' + queryStr, options)
    .map((drugs) => this.processDsTeamSiteDrugs(drugs))
}

processDsTeamSiteDrugs(response) {
    return <any[]>response.json()
}
```

An example response array is

```
[{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":null,"createdAt":"2017-12-09T05:34:30.816Z","version":"AAAAAAAAJ6Q=","id":"48","type":"mg/ml","allConcentration":"15mg/ml","concentration":"15mg/ml","animalTypeId":"af280864-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","notes":"q4-6h","perWeightMax":2.00,"perWeightMin":0.25,"perWeight":0.00,"perWeightTypeId":"c51d9efe-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","route":"SQ,IM","indication":"Analgesia","alternateNames":"","name":"Morphine","drugCategory":"Analgesic"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":null,"createdAt":"2017-12-09T05:34:30.843Z","version":"AAAAAAAAJ7g=","id":"72","type":"mg/ml","allConcentration":"15mg/ml","concentration":"15mg/ml","animalTypeId":"af280e7c-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","notes":"q4-6h","perWeightMax":0.30,"perWeightMin":0.10,"perWeight":0.00,"perWeightTypeId":"c51d9efe-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","route":"SQ,IM","indication":"Analgesia","alternateNames":"","name":"Morphine","drugCategory":"Analgesic"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":null,"createdAt":"2017-12-09T05:34:30.846Z","version":"AAAAAAAAJ70=","id":"78","type":"mg/ml","allConcentration":"15mg/ml","concentration":"15mg/ml","animalTypeId":"af280e7c-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","notes":"use with mIdazolam or diazepam","perWeightMax":0.00,"perWeightMin":0.00,"perWeight":0.50,"perWeightTypeId":"c51d9efe-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","route":"SQ,IM","indication":"Premed","alternateNames":"","name":"Morphine","drugCategory":"Anesthesia"},{"deleted":false,"updatedAt":null,"createdAt":"2017-12-09T05:34:30.85Z","version":"AAAAAAAAJ74=","id":"79","type":"mg/ml","allConcentration":"15mg/ml","concentration":"15mg/ml","animalTypeId":"af280864-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","notes":"given with 0.05mg/kg Ace IM","perWeightMax":0.00,"perWeightMin":0.00,"perWeight":0.50,"perWeightTypeId":"c51d9efe-db83-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a","route":"SQ,IM","indication":"Premed","alternateNames":"","name":"Morphine","drugCategory":"Anesthesia"}]
```

Expected result

"Dosage:" + drug.Name + "-" + drug.AlternateNames + " (" + drug.Type + ") " + drug.Indication
Dosage:  Morphine- (mg/ml) Anesthesia Premed

Comment: If the request to the server is working fine, we don't need to see the code which retrieves the array of objects. (Or is there a problem in the code you want addressed?) What is stopping you from adding a `displayname` property to your objects?

Comment: @4castle i think he just does not know how to do that

Comment: I don't have control over the odata function on the server easily.  I would prefer to handle on the client.  I removed the excess server code in the example.  Thanks.

Comment: Please share the `odata` and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

After you get a `Promise` for your array of objects using `response.json()`, you can use `then` to make modifications to the array of objects once the response is available.

```
processDsTeamSiteDrugs(response) {
  return response.json().then((drugs) => {
    for (const drug of drugs) {
       drug.displayname = `Dosage: ${drug.Name}-${drug.AlternateNames}(${drug.Type}) ${drug.Indication}`;
    }
    return drugs;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think this is on track but I am using rxjs and angular 4.  I am not very familiar with them but I think I need to use a combination of map and flatMap rather than then.   If I replace then with map I don't get an error but I don't see the new displayName property.   I am a real newbie at this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointer.  I was able to solve this using the map operator combined with 4castles code.

```
 processDsTeamSiteDrugs(response) {

    return response.json().map((drugs) => {
      drugs.displayName = `Dosage: ${drugs.name}-${drugs.alternateNames}(${drugs.type}) ${drugs.indication}`;

      return <any[]>drugs;
    });
  }
```